# Can "dumb" ethernet hub device be used for breaking security on Ethernet cable connection?

Tags: security, ethernet, tcpdump, tshark

Many people will still know about those old ethernet "hub"-devices - also called "dumb" device or "Ethernet signal concentrator". Did anyone ever try to "listen to ANY traffic" on such port through an interface in promiscuous mode?

Some `tcpdump` or `tshark` or `wireshark` probably can be used for that, right?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, are you asking if anyone has ever tried to listen to traffic on a hub?

Comment: If you question is whether one can capture all traffic on a hub using a NIC in promiscuous mode via a packet capture program, then yes. I think technically wireshark doesn't do any capturing, rather it uses libpcap, but effectively wireshark is an example. If you have a different question, could you perhaps this original one a bit to clarify?

Comment: Isn't this "network-sniffing 101" from the 1990s?

Comment: I think the big problem here is assuming that point to point ethernet means the traffic is secure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is what these devices are used for these days. I keep some around for this exact use-case.

However do not think of the functionality of an Ethernet switched-hub as a security feature. They are allowed to leak: they will do this when ever a device has not spoken, so its location is not know, or whenever the number of slots in the table is full, and the switch forgets about a device. The switching is **only** for performance, NOT security.